# Modeless form cannot receive keyboard input in Excel Add-in developed by Delphi

Tags: excel, delphi, com, vcl

Is it bug of VCL??
Non modal form cannot receive input in Excel COM Add in.
But the very same code of C# works fine.

Demo:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1eKermBZdgXdT7KtfJeZWxYiUwjDNRAst

C# Demo:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1tdcgkbHU8cExVhHrmFsQeA5oqjlzxN3k

Delphi Code:

```
procedure TDelphiAddIn1.OnStartupComplete(var custom: PSafeArray);
var
  LForm: TForm1;
begin
  LForm := TForm1.Create(nil);
  LForm.Show;
end;
```

C# Code:

```
public void OnStartupComplete(ref System.Array custom)
{
    new Form1().Show();
}
```

Delphi Version: Delphi 10.1 Berlin update2
(1. Steps:Compile the project.
 2. Open cmd as Administrator,  use  regsvr32.exe DLLPath to register the output DLL
 3.Open Excel )[image]

Comment: If the modal-less Form is being shown in the context of a thread inside the Excel process, there is likely no message loop running to let the VCL process input messages.  Displaying a VCL Form modally runs its own message loop.  That, or your video implies that Excel is stealing the user input.

Comment: Modal form works correctly. But user need interact with Excel when my form is shown( pick cell from excel, and select the active cell). can i let vcl form behave like the .net form ?

Comment: Excel has a terrible habit of stealing user input. I have issues with it all the time, not even related to programming.

Comment: My WinZip cannot open your Delphi demo and in any case you should not post a question which requires downloads from an external source, the q should be self-contained instead.  Anyway, are you using a 3rd party library like https://www.add-in-express.com/?utm_campaign=adx1&utm_source=adx&utm_medium=search&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI75yxkfrz2AIVSzobCh2CzgBHEAAYASAAEgL8KPD_BwE to implement your add-in.

Comment: It seems my winrar version is too high. I updated the link with zip format.  The issue cannot be described by some lines of code, so i upload it to google drive.   I'm not using add-in express, just implement the IDTExtensibility2 interface. ( but add-in express have the same issue)

Comment: Try to set Application.Handle := ExcelApp.HWND , but didn't solve it.

Comment: Still cannot solve this issue

Comment: @RemyLebeau After many searches, I think it's impossible to solve this in VCL. Since it needs start another UI thread and run message loop in it.